# Find inverse of rational function $f(x) = \frac{x^3+2}{x-3}$ when x not equal to 3

Tags: functions, inverse-function

Question:

[image]
I'm trying to find inverse of $f(x) = \frac{x^3+2}{x-3}$ for an assignment.

$y = \frac{x^3+2}{x-3}, x\neq3$

Replace $x$ and $y$.

$x = \frac{y^3+2}{y-3}$

$x(y-3) = y^3 + 2$

$xy - 3x = y^3 + 2$

I don't know how to proceed after this. Ideally I want to get $y = \text{(in terms of x)}$. But I can't seem to do that due to term $xy$ and lack of other common factors. Please help!

Comment: In the title, you have $x^2+2$. In the body, you have $x^3+2$. Please edit for consistency. (You also go from $x-3$ to $x+3$.)

Comment: I have fixed it.

Comment: The function is not globally invertible... in which interval(s) do you want to define the inverse?

Comment: Solving with a CAS gives ugly results (either with $x-3$ or $x+3$) which seems weird for an assignment supposed to be solved by hand. So I suppose there are still more typos.

Comment: There isn't a maths editor for this site, it is highly recommended you familiarise yourself with MathJax format, it's is immensely useful not just here but in many places. And I see no one being condescending here, there are people asking for the context of the question and/or for you to confirm the accuracy of everything within the question. If you can do so then we can more effectively help you find a solution.

Comment: @PierreCarre this is all there is to the question. I've attached a screenshot.

Comment: @LoganM I'm new to the site. Thank you for the suggestion. I will familiarize myself with the format. I've attached a screenshot of the question.

Comment: For info the tutorial is here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. Apart from that I still suspect a typo in the book itself.

Comment: Your working seems fine this far, if I rearrange it: $y^3-xy+(3x+2)=0$ we have a depressed cubic equation. This one most certainly doesn't have a nice solution, so I imagine it is a typo in the book. I'd say to skip this question (or find an alternative similar one online).

Comment: See [Wikipedia - Depressed Cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Depressed_cubic).

Comment: $x$ and $y$ implicit in an equation may be what the book is looking for in the answer. You may want to double check that they exactly want an explicit answer.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\neq 3$ $$y= \frac{x^3+2}{x-3}\quad \implies \quad x^3-y \,x+(3y+2)=0$$  For $y>0$, following the steps given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation), we have
$$\Delta=4 y^3-27 (3 y+2)^2$$ which is negative; so, only one real root.

Using the [hyperbolic solution for one real root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Hyperbolic_solution_for_one_real_root), we end with
$$x=-\frac{2 \sqrt{y} }{\sqrt{3}}\cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{ 3\sqrt{3}}{2}\frac{ (3
   y+2)}{y\sqrt y}\right)\right)$$

If you dont know the solution of cubic equations, there is more likely a typo in the textbook. It is not impossible the the problem was in fact $y= \frac{x^\color{red}{\large 2}+2}{x-3}$ (as you wrote in the first version of the post).

Comment: Reading your answer one may be led to believe that we can find an inverse in both $(-\infty, 3)$ and $(3, +\infty)$, which is not the case.